# regex for non-alphabet character preceding and succeeding the match

Tags: regex

I have a list of documents from where I have to fetch some result based on a given match. I am using regex for this. I am using this regex to match my query in the documents

```
(.*)query(.*)
```

Their is a issue in this regex. for example if you are searching for query "mba" then regex will be

```
(.*)mba(.*)
```

Its giving me result like this

```
    (mca or mba) along with doeacc 'b' level  // correct "mba" preceeded by '(' 
    academy of theatre arts/dramatic arts, university of mumbai // not fine "mba" comes in mumbai
    aditya college of mba // correct
    agrawal institute of management & technology, mumbai // not fine "mba" comes in mumbai
    agricultural college & research institute, coimbatore // not fine "mba" comes in coimbatore
    agricultural college and research institute, coimbatore // not fine "mba" comes in coimbatore
```

If I want to check that the character preceding and succeeding the query

```
`"mba" in this case
```

is a non alphabet ie not in[a-z] and [A-Z]
Is their a way to exclude given characters in regex

Thanks

Comment: Its in python, but what difference does it make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this match is with the `\b` anchor, which matches word boundaries:

```
\bmba\b
```

The `\b` anchor does not match a character, but the zero-width boundary between a word character and a non-word character.  So `\bmba\b` will only match if `mba` is preceded by a non-word character like `(` or `"` and followed by a non-word character.